Does a LEGO physics sim exist?
I'm currently in the market for a LEGO CAD that supports physics simulation. For example,

Simulation of flexible parts
Gravity and weight
Bounce
Technic movement

I currently use BrickLink Studio, on a Macbook.

This question is similar to: Virtual LEGO / Technics / Mindstorms simulation environments. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Importing LEGO models via Mecabricks into Blender 3D is often done, but I'm not sure how well it works for the physics parts.
